# Tesseract 3.01 and Pocket-OCR build issues

Tags: ios, ocr, tesseract

I got some issues as below while try to build [Pocket-OCR](https://github.com/AalokParikh/Pocket-OCR)

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::SetVariable(char const*, char const*)",
>   referenced from:
>         -[OCRDisplayViewController viewDidLoad] in OCRDisplayViewController.o
>   "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::TesseractRect(unsigned char const*, int, int,
>   int, int, int, int)", referenced from:
>         -[OCRDisplayViewController readAndProcessImage:] in OCRDisplayViewController.o
>         -[OCRDisplayViewController threadedReadAndProcessImage:] in OCRDisplayViewController.o
>   "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::AllWordConfidences()", referenced from:
>         -[OCRDisplayViewController viewDidLoad] in OCRDisplayViewController.o   "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::End()",
>   referenced from:
>         -[OCRDisplayViewController dealloc] in OCRDisplayViewController.o   "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init(char
>   const*, char const*, tesseract::OcrEngineMode, char**, int,
>   GenericVector const*, GenericVector const*, bool)",
>   referenced from:
>         tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init(char const*, char const*) in OCRDisplayViewController.o   "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::TessBaseAPI()",
>   referenced from:
>         -[OCRDisplayViewController viewDidLoad] in OCRDisplayViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture
>   i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

What should I do to resolve this issues?

I search on goole for answer but does'n get much help to solve the issues.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same error. I've checked my libraries and they're at the correct location. I tried every solution given here. Non worked. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this and also got new links and examples that are working fine and have completed my demo project

May these links are useful for others who want's to use it.

[Example One](https://github.com/AalokParikh/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo)

Now got the exact link from where I am able to develop my demo project.

[Example Which I used](http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/)

Comment: As not know the exact link I am going to put some links which I referred to get proper solution

Answer (score 1):

you can reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849517/c-linking-problems-seems-like-i-cant-link-against-standard-c-stuff) solution on SO

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion +1 for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Though the answer is already accepted I found the solution that worked for me:

Apparently xCode does not add frameworks automatically to the "Link Binary With Libraries"- and "Copy Bundle Resources"-lists.

You can find them by clicking on your projectname (blue icon) and then go to "Build Phases" and add them to both lists. Then change from "Required" to "Optional". Both can be seen in the screenshot.

[image]