# C++ link error with Xcode 5 when changing iOS Deployment Target to iOS 7.0

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I've upgraded to Xcode 5, and am able to build my project fine using existing settings.

Updating the Base SDK to 7.0 doesn't cause any problems.

But, when I change the iOS Deployment Target to iOS 7.0, I start getting link errors for standard C++ symbols.  e.g.:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 std::string::empty() const", referenced from...
```

What I have tried:

- Explicitly linking standard C++ libraries
- Changing the "C++ Standard Library" setting in Xcode 5.   Tried both libstdc++, libc++ and "Compiler Default"

It just isn't finding the C++ symbols if the Deployment Target is set to iOS 7.0, and it does if it is set to iOS 6.1.

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yes, clean and rebuild, and Clean Build Folder as well...

Comment: try `Build Settings -> Compile Sources As -> Objective-C++`

Comment: Thanks.  The C++ references are from included from a library -- I tried that setting (was "According to File Type") when building the library, and it didn't have an impact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that if XCode can't find any C++ files in the project, then it assumes that libstd++ is not required. So, you have to manually add a C++ file to the project (an empty .mm file would be enough).

All the credits go to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19250215/870011) in this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959691/ios7-only-stdlibc-linking-issue).

Comment: Adding a dummy .mm file to the project worked.   This solves the problem, but if anyone knows a better workaround it would be nice to hear.

Comment: Totally agree, this is still a workaround. I guess the best solution would be to have XCode working. If you find out a better solution, please share it here as well.

Comment: We just had this problem, too, and found that a .mm file alone was not enough. We had to tell Xcode (version 5) to link with the standard C++ library, too.