# Undefined symbols for architecture error when deployment target is 7.0

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios7, linker-errors

I am using third party frameworks in my native iOS application (bunch of .a libraries). My application is developed with XCode 5 base SDK 7.0.

The libraries compile and link fine when the deployment target is 6.1 (library and header search paths are good). However, when I change the deployment target to be 7.0, I get the following linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "std::string::find_last_of(char const*, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      GetExecutionDir(ECTemplateString<char>&, char*, bool) in myLibrary.a(moPlatForm.o)
  "std::string::find(char const*, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      ParseLog(std::string const&, unsigned int&, CmoDateTime&, int&, std::string&) in myLibrary.a(AppLog.o)
  "std::string::size() const", referenced from:
      mo::CmoParam::WriteToStream(void*, mo::STREAM_STATE*) in myLibrary.a(moParams.o)
  "std::string::c_str() const", referenced from:
      GetExecutionDir(ECTemplateString<char>&, char*, bool) in myLibrary.a(moPlatForm.o)
      CMocaFileTransfer::UpdateParamsForGetTraceFiles(mo::CmoParamList&, long) in myLibrary.a(RobieFileTransfer.o)
      CMocaFileTransfer::AddTraceFileForUpload(std::string const&, std::string const&) in myLibrary.a(RobieFileTransfer.o)
      CMocaFileTransfer::CreateParamsForSendTraceFiles(mo::CmoObject&) in myLibrary.a(RobieFileTransfer.o)
      mo::CmoParam::WriteToStream(void*, mo::STREAM_STATE*) in myLibrary.a(moParams.o)
      ParseLog(std::string const&, unsigned int&, CmoDateTime&, int&, std::string&) in myLibrary.a(AppLog.o)
      CAppLog::LogExists(unsigned int) in myLibrary.a(AppLog.o)
      ...
```

Libraries are a bit old, I am not sure if there is a compatibility issue. I am not planning to support iOS 6 so I need to set the deployment target as 7.0. Any kind of help/direction would be great.

Comment: Any reason why these are getting compiled to i386? I'm guessing you need to remove i386 from the target build settings so only armv7 and armv7s is in there.

Comment: I have tried playing with the architectures. I don't think it is an architecture issue. By the way, libraries only support armv7, so armv7s is out of the question.

Comment: I hear ya, but at the very top of the error it says architecture i386. Apparently it doesn't support that either :-)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am also facing the same kind of errors from trying to link to third party c++ libraries (libjingle). My environment is Xcode 5.0 and deployment target iOS 7.0. I just switched to deployment target iOS 6.1 for time being and the errors are gone. I guess for deployment target iOS 7.0, you need to add an empty .mm file (as mentioned in the below answers but I will try that later).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It turns out that if XCode can't find any C++ files in the project, then it assumes that libstd++ is not required. So, you have to manually add a C++ file to the project (an empty .mm file would be enough). That is the solution.

All the credits go to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19250215/870011) in this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959691/ios7-only-stdlibc-linking-issue).

Comment: Voodoo stuff! Worked for me

Comment: It also works if you add any C++ header #import to .pch file.

Comment: Wow. This still is a problem in XCode 6.1.1 and this solution still works. Bananas. Thank you for putting the answer here too!

Comment: How to add this empty .mm file  can you tell me ??

Answer (score 46):

for me, including the '**stdc++.6.0.9.dylib**' instead of '**stdc++.dylib**' into the dependencies resolved the linker errors too

Comment: That solved the problem. Thanks! What is the difference between these two libraries?

Comment: I believe, that specifying a library directly, skips the Xcode logic for 'optimising' and checking if project contains C++ source files

Comment: This solved the problem for me as well - without having to add any empty C++ files.

Comment: Still an issue with Xcode 6.3.2, and this fix still works.

Comment: what is about other linker flag what to set in that

Answer (score 8):

It looks as if myLibrary.a was built with calls to C++ code and used libstdc++ as its C++ standard library.  Your application project probably specifies libc++ instead, perhaps as the compiler default.

Try switching back to libstdc++ and see if the errors go away (or change, at least).  Your eventual solution is likely to be a library that's built against the new standard library.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out but nope. This doesn't fix the issue. Actually, I remember getting errors from the library with the description 'libc++abi.dylib: handler threw exception'. So, I am guessing the library is compiled with libc++.