# Unable to build AllJoyn dependent project after upgrading to ios7

Tags: ios, xcode5, alljoyn

I develop an enterprise iOS platform that uses [AllJoyn](https://allseenalliance.org/developer-resources/alljoyn-open-source-project) to communicate between the various tablets. The app has been fairly stable for a few months, but since Apple is discontinuing support for iOS<7 we are moving the platform to iOS7. After updating the project and getting rid of all of the compiler warnings I kept getting the following linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
std::allocator<char> > const&) in libajdaemon.a(json_writer.o)
```

After searching the AllSeen support site I found this [article](https://www.alljoyn.org/forums/developers/sample-applications-dont-compile-out-box-ios-armv7s-devices) that seemed relevant. I tried fiddling with the architectures (removing and adding armv7, armv7s and i386), I checked that the location of the AllJoyn SDK was correct, but it definitely wasn't a path or AllJoyn library issue.

I then tried tracking down potential solutions on Stack Overflow and found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271856/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-error-when-deployment-target-is-7-0). Manually adding libstdc++.dylib but adding libstdc++6.0.9.dylib made my project successfully compile. This however created issues with the run time version of the app.

Solution:

I finally came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959691/ios7-only-stdlibc-linking-issue/19250215) describing issues related to automatically detecting the appropriate C++ library to link in XCode. After implementing @rimestad's solution I finally got the whole project to work by

> Ensur[ing] that C++ Standard Library is set to libstdc++ (GNU c++ standard library) in the Build Settings

Last query:

I still have one more small question that bugs me... why does the iOS6 build (in XCode 5.1) correctly detect that my project needs the GNU C++ standard library while exactly the same IDE set to build for iOS7 (with exactly the same code) fails to detect this?