# Parse for iOS - Undefined symbols for architecture i386 - iPhone 4s, iPhone 5

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios4

I am getting few similar `Undefined symbols for architecture i386:` ... `"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFAnalytics", referenced from:` errors while building for iPhone 4s simulator or iPhone 5 simulator.

With iPhone 5s-> everything works great. What am I doing wrong?

I have Parse and Facebook SDK's installed via CocoaPods:

```
    target 'My app' do
    platform :ios, '8.0'
    pod 'Parse'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    end
```

**Update 1:**

I have architectures selected like this:

```
    //Debug, Release
    ARCHS = $(ARCHS_STANDARD)

    //Debug, Release
    VALID_ARCHS = arm64 armv7 armv7s
```

Comment: i think this is what u are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552855/xcode-6-1-missing-required-architecture-x86-64-in-file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271856/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-error-when-deployment-target-is-7-0

Comment: @youngdero Thanks for the reply. Yes, I think my problem has something to do with the same thing, but neither of the solutions really did not work for me. I am using CocoaPods and everything have been worked earlier, but now I am getting these errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got it working with the help of CocoaPods community. Problem was with the DerivedData. I cleaned DerivedData for my project (in XCode 7, Window -> Projects) and it started working perfectly again.

More details https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4736.

Comment: thanks this worked for me- saved me hours of messing around!