# App get crashed in std::string::size() in iOS 7.0 platform, but works fine in iOS 6.0 or earlier

Tags: ios, iphone, string, ios7, nsstring

For some days I am facing this strange problem. My app works fine for iOS 6.0 but same app gets crashed in iOS 7.0. And the crash point denoted by xcode is std::string operation. But couldn't find any wrong string operation in my code. Here is the backtrace-

```
0 libstdc++.6.dylib 0x3a548dfc std::string::size() const + 0
1 SimpleChat 0x005ebf82 std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (basic_string.tcc:681)
```

Is there anyone familiar with this type of crash. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this one might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959691/ios7-only-stdlibc-linking-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I am posting my answer here so that an user can find the solution of the issue.

The issue was related to compiler options. In my case I was setting wrong libstd++ for iOS 7.0
So one should check the compiler options carefully.