# (GStreamer) How can I get Taglib and Core Audio Utility Classes to work together?

Tags: c++, ios, gstreamer, taglib

I need the [Core Audio Utility Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CoreAudioUtilityClasses/Introduction/Intro.html) for my app, but every time I add the files to my project TagLib goes haywire. They're all C++, which I thought could be causing problems mixing with Obj-C, but even when I only add the files without linking them anywhere I get the same compile errors.

Do you know what the problem might be? How can I debug this?

Here are some of the linker errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::find(wchar_t const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      TagLib::String::find(TagLib::String const&, int) const in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tstring.cpp.o)
  "std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::rfind(wchar_t const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      TagLib::String::rfind(TagLib::String const&, int) const in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tstring.cpp.o)
  "std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::_M_leak_hard()", referenced from:
      TagLib::String::String(std::string const&, TagLib::String::Type) in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tstring.cpp.o)
      TagLib::String::prepare(TagLib::String::Type) in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tstring.cpp.o)
      TagLib::String::String(std::string const&, TagLib::String::Type) in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tstring.cpp.o)
      TagLib::String::String(char const*, TagLib::String::Type) in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tstring.cpp.o)
      TagLib::String::String(TagLib::ByteVector const&, TagLib::String::Type) in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tstring.cpp.o)
      TagLib::String::to8Bit(bool) const in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tstring.cpp.o)
      TagLib::String::begin() in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tstring.cpp.o)
      ...
  "std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<wchar_t> const&)", referenced from:
      TagLib::String::~String() in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tstring.cpp.o)
      TagLib::String::String(wchar_t const*, TagLib::String::Type) in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tstring.cpp.o)
      TagLib::String::~String() in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tstring.cpp.o)
      TagLib::String::~String() in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tstring.cpp.o)
      TagLib::String::startsWith(TagLib::String const&) const in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tstring.cpp.o)
      TagLib::String::substr(unsigned int, unsigned int) const in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tstring.cpp.o)
      TagLib::String::upper() const in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tstring.cpp.o)
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      __GLOBAL__I_a in GStreamer(libgsttaglib_a_x86_64_-libgsttaglib_la-gstapev2mux.o)
      __GLOBAL__I_a in GStreamer(libgsttaglib_a_x86_64_-libgsttaglib_la-gstid3v2mux.o)
      __GLOBAL__I_a in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tbytevector.cpp.o)
      __GLOBAL__I_a in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tstringlist.cpp.o)
      __GLOBAL__I_a in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-apetag.cpp.o)
      __GLOBAL__I_a in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-id3v2framefactory.cpp.o)
      __GLOBAL__I_a in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-commentsframe.cpp.o)
      ...
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      __GLOBAL__I_a in GStreamer(libgsttaglib_a_x86_64_-libgsttaglib_la-gstapev2mux.o)
      __GLOBAL__I_a in GStreamer(libgsttaglib_a_x86_64_-libgsttaglib_la-gstid3v2mux.o)
      __GLOBAL__I_a in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tbytevector.cpp.o)
      __GLOBAL__I_a in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-tstringlist.cpp.o)
      __GLOBAL__I_a in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-apetag.cpp.o)
      __GLOBAL__I_a in GStreamer(libtag_a_x86_64_-id3v2framefactory.cpp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959691/ios7-only-stdlibc-linking-issue). Only had to switch the C++ standard library to libstdc++ in build settings. Works perfectly now.