# "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:

Tags: ios, linker

when I set deployment target iOS 6+,then build,the errors from a third SDK shows.
But, it runs fine when deployment target is iOS 6. It is unbelievable!Is anybody can help me,thanks very much!!

**Error:**

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "std::_List_node_base::transfer(std::_List_node_base*,
>   std::_List_node_base*)", referenced from:
>         std::list
>
> > ::_M_transfer(std::_List_iterator, std::_List_iterator,
> >     std::_List_iterator) in
> >     libccpapisdk.a(vie_receiver.o)
> >           std::list
> >     ::_M_transfer(std::_List_iterator, std::_List_iterator,
> >     std::_List_iterator) in
> >     libccpapisdk.a(frame_buffer.o)
> >           std::list
> >     ::_M_transfer(std::_List_iterator,
> >     std::_List_iterator,
> >     std::_List_iterator)
> >     in libccpapisdk.a(remote_bitrate_estimator.o)
> >           std::list >::_M_transfer(std::_List_iterator, std::_List_iterator, std::_List_iterator) in
> >     libccpapisdk.a(remote_bitrate_estimator.o)
> >           std::list
> >     ::_M_transfer(std::_List_iterator, std::_List_iterator,
> >     std::_List_iterator) in
> >     libccpapisdk.a(forward_error_correction.o)
> >           std::list
> >     ::_M_transfer(std::_List_iterator,
> >     std::_List_iterator,
> >     std::_List_iterator)
> >     in libccpapisdk.a(forward_error_correction.o)
> >     "std::__throw_runtime_error(char const*)", referenced from:
> >           std::list
> >     ::_M_check_equal_allocators(std::list >&) in
> >     libccpapisdk.a(vie_receiver.o)
> >           std::list
> >     ::_M_check_equal_allocators(std::list >&) in
> >     libccpapisdk.a(frame_buffer.o)
> >           std::list
> >     ::_M_check_equal_allocators(std::list >&) in
> >     libccpapisdk.a(remote_bitrate_estimator.o)
> >           std::list >::_M_check_equal_allocators(std::list >&) in libccpapisdk.a(remote_bitrate_estimator.o)
> >           std::list
> >     ::_M_check_equal_allocators(std::list >&) in
> >     libccpapisdk.a(forward_error_correction.o)
> >           std::list
> >     ::_M_check_equal_allocators(std::list
> >     &) in libccpapisdk.a(forward_error_correction.o)   "std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)", referenced
> >     from:
> >           std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >::operator--() in libccpapisdk.a(map.o)
> >           MD5::hexdigest(bool) const in libccpapisdk.a(md5.o)
> >           ...   "std::basic_string, std::allocator >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
> >           CheckPrivateCloud(void*) in libccpapisdk.a(CCPClient.o)
> >           std::pair::~pair() in libccpapisdk.a(servicecore.o)
> >           ServiceCore::ring_start(char const*, int, int) in libccpapisdk.a(mediaprocess.o)
> >           ServiceCore::serphone_set_video_window_and_request_video_accord_sip(char
> >     const*, void*, char const*, char const*, int) in
> >     libccpapisdk.a(mediaprocess.o)
> >           ServiceCore::serphone_stop_conference_video_accord_sip(char const*, char const*, char const*) in libccpapisdk.a(mediaprocess.o)
> >           ServiceCore::serphone_check_video_conference_request_failed() in libccpapisdk.a(mediaprocess.o)
> >           TRESTClient::TRESTClient(std::string const&, int, std::string const&, std::string, std::string) in libccpapisdk.a(RESTClient.o)
> >           ... ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: May be it shows framework error. May be you forgot to add some framework or compiler flag (If need). I don't think so its about deployment target.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have find the solution.I was using  "libstdc++" instead of "compiler default".Reference link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959691/ios7-only-stdlibc-linking-issue

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode Build Settings,there is one option named "Build Active Architecture Only".Changing to Yes for debug mode may help you

Comment: I have done as U,but it still no worked.Thanks for your help too!