# Weird error when trying to build

Tags: ios, objective-c, compilation, compiler-errors, time.h

I have this code in a class called `ctime`:

```
#include <__config>
#include <time.h>

#if !defined(_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_PRAGMA_SYSTEM_HEADER)
#pragma GCC system_header
#endif

_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMEPSACE_STD

using ::clock_t;
using ::size_t;
using ::time_t;
using ::tm;
using ::clock;
using ::difftime;
using ::mktime;
using ::time;
using ::asctime;
using ::ctime;
using ::gmtime;
using ::localtime;
using ::strftime;

_LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD
```

But I keep getting these errors:

[image: errors]

Anyone knows what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the answer, it was probably because I had a framework with a header inside called `time.h` which is saved name. I changed my file to `mytime.h` and it compiled perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Issue may be related to C++ standard library not found at the compile time

You can try the following ways:

- Add an empty .mm file to you project!
  Ensure that C++ Standard Library is set to libstdc++ (GNU c++ standard library) in the Build Settings
  Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19250215/4557505 
  **else**
- add -lstdc++ to Other Linker Flags! in the build settings 
  **else**
- add libstdc++.dylib/tbd and libstdc++.6.dylib/tbd in the build phases -> Link Binary with Library